# Split integers based on a value in second column, assign new values, and, recombine into new dataset

Tags: r, list, split

In `R`, I have a `2xn` matrix of data containing all integers.

The first column indicates the size of an item. Some of these sizes were due to merging, so the second column indicates the number of items that went into that size (including 1) (calling it 'index'). The sum of the indices indicate how many items were actually in the original data.

I now need to create a new data set that splits any merged sizes back out according to the number in the index, resulting in a `2xn` vector (with a new length `n` according the the total number of indices) and a second column all 1's.

I need this split to happen in two ways.

- "Homogeneously" where any merged sizes are assigned to the number of indices as homogeneously as possible. For instance, a size of `6` with index of `3` would now be `c(2,2,2)`. **Importantly,** all number have to be integers, so it should be something like c(1,2) or c(2,1). It cant be c(1.5,1.5).
- "Heterogeneously" where the number of sizes are skewed to assign `1` to all positions in the index except one, which would contain the reminder. For instance, of a size of `6` with index of `3`, it would now be `c(1,1,4)` or any combination of 1, 1, and 4.

Below I am providing some sample data that gives an example of what I have, what I want, and what I have tried.

```r
#Example data that I have
Y.have<-cbind(c(19,1,1,1,1,4,3,1,1,8),c(3,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3))
```

The data show that three items went into the size of 19 for the first row, one item went into the size one in the second column, and so on. Importantly, in these data there were originally 15 items (i.e. `sum(Y.have[,2])`), some of which got merged, so the final data will need to be of length 15.

What I want the data to look like is:

```r
####Homogenous separation - split values evenly as possible
#' The value of 19 in row 1 is now a vector of c(6,6,7) (or any combination thereof, i.e. c(6,7,6) is fine) since the position in the second column is a 3
#' Rows 2-5 are unchanged since they have a 1 in the second column
#' The value of 4 in row 6 is now a vecttor of c(2,2) since the position of the second column is a 2
#' Rows 7-9 are unchanged since they have a 1 in the second column
#' The value of 8 in row 10 is now a vector of c(3,3,2) (or any combination thereof) since the position in the second column is a 3
Y.want.hom<-cbind(c(c(6,6,7),1,1,1,1,c(2,2),3,1,1,c(3,3,2)),c(rep(1,times=sum(Y.have[,2]))))

####Heterogenous separation - split values with as many singles as possible, 
#' The value of 19 in row 1 is now a vector of c(1,1,17) (or any combination thereof, i.e. c(1,17,1) is fine) since the position in the second column is a 3
#' Rows 2-5 are unchanged since they have a 1 in the second column
#' The value of 4 in row 6 is now a vecttor of c(1,3) since the position of the second column is a 2
#' Rows 7-9 are unchanged since they have a 1 in the second column
#' The value of 8 in row 10 is now a vector of c(1,1,6) (or any combination thereof) since the position in the second column is a 3
Y.want.het<-cbind(c(c(1,1,17),1,1,1,1,c(1,3),3,1,1,c(1,1,6)),c(rep(1,times=sum(Y.have[,2]))))
```

Note that the positions of the integers in the final data don't matter since they will all have one index case.

I have tried splitting the data (`split`) according to index case. This creates a list with a length according to the number of unique index values. I then iterated through that positions in that list and divided by the position.

```r
a<-split(Y.have[,1],Y.have[,2]) #Split into a list according to the index
b<-list() #initiate new list
for (i in 1:length(a)){ 
  b[[i]]<-a[[i]]/i #get homogenous values
  b[[i]]<-rep(b[i],times=i) #repeat the values based on the number of indicies
}
Y.test<-cbind(unlist(b),rep(1,times=length(unlist(c)))) #create new dataset
```

This was a terrible approach. First, it will produce decimals. Second, the position in the list does not necessarily equal the index number (i.e. if there was no index of 2, the second position would be the next lowest index, but would divide by 2).

However, it at least allowed me to separate out the data by index, manipulate it, and recombine it to a proper length. I now need help in that middle part - manipulating the data for both homogeneous and heterogenous reassignment. I would prefer base r, but any approach would certainly be fine! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here might be one approach.

Create two functions for homogeneous and heterogeneous splits:

```
get_hom_ints <- function(M, N) {
  vec <- rep(floor(M/N), N)
  for (i in seq_len(M - sum(vec))) {
    vec[i] <- vec[i] + 1
  }
  vec
}

get_het_ints <- function(M, N) {
  vec <- rep(1, N)
  vec[1] <- M - sum(vec) + 1
  vec
}
```

Then use `apply` to go through each row of the matrix:

```
het_vec <- unlist(apply(Y.have, 1, function(x) get_het_ints(x[1], x[2]))) 
unname(cbind(het_vec, rep(1, length(het_vec))))

hom_vec <- unlist(apply(Y.have, 1, function(x) get_hom_ints(x[1], x[2])))
unname(cbind(hom_vec, rep(1, length(het_vec))))
```

**Output**

(heterogeneous)

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   17    1
 [2,]    1    1
 [3,]    1    1
 [4,]    1    1
 [5,]    1    1
 [6,]    1    1
 [7,]    1    1
 [8,]    3    1
 [9,]    1    1
[10,]    3    1
[11,]    1    1
[12,]    1    1
[13,]    6    1
[14,]    1    1
[15,]    1    1
```

(homogeneous)

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    7    1
 [2,]    6    1
 [3,]    6    1
 [4,]    1    1
 [5,]    1    1
 [6,]    1    1
 [7,]    1    1
 [8,]    2    1
 [9,]    2    1
[10,]    3    1
[11,]    1    1
[12,]    1    1
[13,]    3    1
[14,]    3    1
[15,]    2    1
```

Comment: This is such a perfect and elegant solution. In both instances, it seems like you assigned the simplest vector values first then went back in and added the more complex things (i.e. adding the extra `1` in 'ho'm and remainder in 'het'. Thank you for both providing help here but also how to approach solutions in the future!

Answer (score 1):

`library(partitions)` is created for this type of requirements check it out.
Apply below logics to your code it should work

**ex:**

```
hom <- restrictedparts(19,3)  #where 19 is Y.have[,1][1] and 3 is Y.have[,2][1] as per your data 
print(hom[,ncol(hom)])

#output : 7 6 6

het <- Reduce(intersect, list(which(hom[2,1:ncol(hom)] %in% 1),which(hom[3,1:ncol(hom)] %in% 1)))
hom[,het]

#output : 17 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use integer division (%/%) and modulus (%%). It may not give the exact results you specified ie. 8 and 3 give (2,2,4) rather than (3,3,2), but does generally do what you described.

```
Y.have<-cbind(c(19,1,1,1,1,4,3,1,1,8),c(3,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,3))

homoVec <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Y.have[,1])){
  if (Y.have[i,2] == 1) {
    a = Y.have[i,1]
    homoVec <- append(homoVec, a)
  } else {
    quantNum <- Y.have[i,1]
    indexNum <- Y.have[i,2]
    b <- quantNum %/% indexNum
    c <- quantNum %% indexNum
    a <- c(rep(b, indexNum-1), b + c)
    homoVec <- append(homoVec, a)
  }
}

homoOut <- data.frame(homoVec, 1)

heteroVec <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Y.have[,1])){
  if (Y.have[i,2] == 1) {
    a = 1
    heteroVec <- append(heteroVec, a)
  } else {
    quantNum <- Y.have[i,1]
    indexNum <- Y.have[i,2]
    firstNum <- quantNum - (indexNum - 1)
    a <- c(firstNum, rep(1, indexNum - 1))
    heteroVec <- append(heteroVec, a)
  }
}

heteroOut <- data.frame(heteroVec, 1)
```

If it is really important to have the math exactly as you described in your example then this should work.

```
homoVec <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Y.have[,1])){
  if (Y.have[i,2] == 1) {
    a = Y.have[i,1]
    homoVec <- append(homoVec, a)
  } else {
    quantNum <- Y.have[i,1]
    indexNum <- Y.have[i,2]
    b <- round(quantNum/indexNum)
    roundSum <- b * (indexNum - 1)
    c <- quantNum - roundSum
    a <- c(rep(b, indexNum-1), c)
    homoVec <- append(homoVec, a)
  }
}

homoOut <- data.frame(homoVec, 1)
```